# What am I doing wrong with this jQuery cookie?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using the Zurb jQuery Modal script to bring up a popup box.  when the user clicks the "close" x, I want to set a cookie so they don't see the popup again for 15 days.

For some reason, I can't get this to work, can someone help?

here is the live example:
http://www.realcartips.com/test/modal/demo.html

And here is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if (!(jQuery.cookie("rct"))) {  

    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#myModal').reveal();
    }, 1000);

}
});

$(".close-reveal-modal").click(function () {
    $.cookie("rct", 1, { expires: 15, path: '/' });
});   

</script>
```

Edit:  I forgot to mention I'm using the cookie jQuery plugin

Comment: I would expand on this to say what it *is* doing, and if the cookie is indeed getting set at all.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you're probably using the [cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

Comment: @Gregg try :`if (jQuery.cookie("rct")==null) {`

Comment: @mgraph - I just tried that, but it didn't work.  The popup still keeps coming up.

Comment: @Gregg add and `alert("close")` after `$(".close-reveal-modal").click(function () {` to see if it's fired or not

Comment: OK, just added the alert and it does not fire.

Comment: @Gregg so the problem is that the cookie is never set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$(".close-reveal-modal").live("click",function () {
    alert("fired");
    $.cookie("rct", 1, { expires: 15, path: '/' });
});
```