# How do I create a common jquery disclaimer/verification (yes/no options) window with cookies detection?

Tags: jquery, cookies, dialog, window

I've been having issues with getting a jquery plugin to work.
A jquery window should come up and ask if a user agrees or disagrees to terms.
If the user agrees pressing yes it will store a cookie and the window will not come back untill the cookie expires. If they press no  it will redirect to another url.

The script is below.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/build-a-popup-modal-window-using-the-jquery-reveal-plugin/

How do I integrate jquery.cookies.js to write a cookie when the user clicks on yes/green button? I've googled callbacks and things to no avail.

How do I make the reveal plugin to work in this way?

Please help!

(PS 
A question asked by another user is similar to but is not the same because the it does the same by clicking close and not a yes no button.
[What am I doing wrong with this jQuery cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243510/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-this-jquery-cookie))

Below is what I have so far

```
<!--jQuery-->
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

if (!(jQuery.cookie("agree"))) {  

    $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                    animation: 'fade',                   // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                    animationspeed: 500,                       // how fast animtions are
                    closeonbackgroundclick: false,              // if you click background will modal close?
                    dismissmodalclass: 'close'    // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
                });
}
});

$(".close").live("click",function () {
    $.cookie("agree", 1, { expires: 1, path: '/' });
});     
</script>



</head>
<body>


<div id="modal">
<img src="images/images.jpg" alt="image test" width="360" height="194" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" align="top">
    <div id="heading">heading/div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Do you agree yes or no?</p>

        <a href="#" class="button green close"><img src="images/tick.png">Yes</a>

        <a href="http://google.com" class="button red close"><img src="images/cross.png">No</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so I added the modal.js from the site you linked, to the fiddle to test it... http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/56yGV/  note the console log. Make sure the css to the modal is " #modal {visibility:hidden;} " not " #modal {display:none;} "

Comment: Also, dont hit 'yes' right away...just hit 'no' and refresh the page a few times so you can see that the cookie doesnt set, and all works ell.  After that, hit the 'yes' button and refresh so you can see the cookie does set.

Comment: If you want to mess around with it by changing the cookie values to test... just change the two spots that reference the value. Right now it is set to "iagree"

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, don't forget to click the check mark next to my answer to accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div id="modal">

    <img src="images/images.jpg" alt="image test" width="360" height="194" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" align="top" />

    <div id="heading">heading/div>

    <div id="content">

    <p>Do you agree yes or no?</p>

      <a id='agree' href="#" class="button green close"><img src="images/tick.png" /> Yes </a>            <a href="http://google.com" class="button red close"><img src="images/cross.png" /> No </a>    

    </div>

</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('document').load(function() {


    //Check cookie value
    if ($.cookie("disclaimer") != 'agree') {

        $('#modal').reveal({ 
            animation: 'fade',                   
            animationspeed: 500,                       
            closeonbackgroundclick: false,
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'    
        });

    }


    // Attach click function to button '#agree' to set cookie
    $("body").on("click", "#agree", function () {
        $.cookie("disclaimer", "agree", { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    });



});
```

Comment: Here is a link showing all the different options. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/reveal.php

Comment: I forgot to mention that this script should persist on all pages of the website. It should come up any where at any time as long as the cookie is expired or not present... So it will be a automatic popup

Comment: @Ken Thats fine, you just have to make sure your script is on all pages :)

Comment: Console says  $.cookie is not a function. What's going on? The link sees jquery.cookie.js

Comment: I don't know for sure, it could be the order of the js ... I hope you get this working man!!!

Comment: I'll try to help you out tomorrow, I'm super tired...my bed is calling me! Haha...have a goodnight man